# Python np.delete issue

Tags: python, numpy

```
A = np.array([[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[5,6,7]])
X = np.array([[0, 1, 0]])
for i in xrange(np.shape(X)[0]):
    for j in xrange(np.shape(X)[1]):
        if X[i,j] == 0.0:
            A = np.delete(A, (j), axis=0)
```

I am trying to delete `j` from `A` if in `X` there is 0 at index `j`. I get

```
IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with  size 2.
```

if X is `[[0,1,0]]` then `A` should become `[[3,4,5]]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't call `np.delete` in a loop. It would be quicker to use boolean indexing:

```
In [6]: A[X.astype(bool).any(axis=0)]
Out[6]: array([[3, 4, 5]])
```

`X.astype(bool)` turns 0 into `False` and any non-zero value into `True`:

```
In [9]: X.astype(bool).any(axis=0)
Out[9]: array([False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

the call to `.any(axis=0)` returns `True` if *any* value in a column of `X.astype(bool)` is True, and `False` otherwise.

---

Removing items from a list (or array) while looping over the same list is [a classic
pitfall](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6260089/190597). The problem is cause by
the fact that removing items from the list changes the meaning of ordinal
indexing so that if you use ordinal indexing to remove other items, you may end
up removing the wrong items, or get IndexError if you try to index beyond the
valid range for the modified list.

In your case, when you loop through rows of A and also delete rows of A:

```
for j in xrange(np.shape(X)[1]):
    if X[i,j] == 0.0:
        A = np.delete(A, j, axis=0)
```

each time you modify `A` the index into `A` changes. So

```
        A = np.delete(A, 0, axis=0)
```

deletes the first row of the original `A`, but now the new `A` only has two rows.
So

```
        A = np.delete(A, 2, axis=0)
```

raises an IndexError since 2 refers to the third row, and the new A does not have a third row. This problem is only exacerbated if the `i`-loop causes `A = np.delete(A, j, axis=0)` to be called multiple times too.